# how can I upload a csv file and enter the data into a database, using Flask, postgres and Python?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask

Trying to upload a csv file, open it and then iterate through the rows to insert each field in to the postgres database, I have 2 (identified so far) problems with this. I am using Flask not Django.

1. I get an indentation error, although I cannot for the life of me see where. RESOLVED
2. The heroku logs provide no other feedback so I am unsure even if the file is correctly opened and read.

The csv file is:

```
first_name last_name email etc. # in all 8 columns
John       Smith     john@website.com
```

and the python code is:

```
@app.route("/uploadcsv", methods=['POST'])
def uploadcsv():
csvfile = request.files['file']
with open(csvfile):
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        firstname = row['first_name']
        query = Prospect(first_name=firstname)
        db.session.add(query)
        db.session.commit()
        return "OK"
```

So, there are 2 questions:

1. what is the indentation problem? RESOLVED
2. Is the code correct for uploading, opening and insertion?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't indented the for loop body:

```
for row in data:
    first_name = row['first_name']
    sql = Prospect(first_name=first_name) #truncated for brevity
    db.session.add(sql)
    db.session.commit()
```

If it's not that, then it's probably mixed tabs and spaces. Python can handle one or the other, but never both!

You're better off using the [`csv` Python library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html). There's no need to try parsing csv files yourself!

Comment: thanks I should add that I did import cvs. I will check the tabs and spaces, as you suggest. And the rest? Does it look correct at least in terms of approach?

Comment: Thank you, indentation is resolved. However, the upload and insertion does not work. Heroku gives no reason why, just a 500 response. Please could you give me your view on the code which I have now amended above? Thank you!

Comment: If you're getting a server error, check your logs for the error message.

Comment: thanks but the heroku logs say nothing just "status 500"